# Columnwise combining of three strings throws 'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am puzzled and have no idea what is happening. My script contains the following line. It is used to combine contents of three columns of a dataframe into one of them (only for rows that fulfill the specified condition):

```
    share_data_sm[yr]['MMR']= np.where((share_data_sm[yr]['MC']!='MA') & (share_data_sm[yr]['MC']!=' ') & (share_data_sm[yr]['MY']!=' '), share_data_sm[yr]['MC'].astype(str) + share_data_sm[yr]['N'].astype(str) + share_data_sm[yr]['MFR'].astype(str), share_data_sm[yr]['MFR'])
```

'share_data_sm' is a dictionary of dataframes - one table per 'yr'. What puzzles me the most, is that the error is thrown only for one particular value of 'yr' (command is a part of a loop that goes over several values of 'yr' and except for this one particular value (2021) the script runs smoothly). I though maybe there are some peculiarities in the data contents of the 2021 dataframe, but nothing exceptional there everything is exactly as the others. The following is traceback from console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "…ipykernel_1380/3858926177.py", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('…work_folder/Groups/Structure/shareholding.py', wdir='…_work_folder/Groups/Structure')
File "…pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 167, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
File "…pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents + "\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "…work_folder/Groups/Structure/shareholding.py", line 281, in <module>
share_data_sm[yr]['MMR']= np.where((share_data_sm[yr]['MC']!='MA') & (share_data_sm[yr]['MC']!=' ') & (share_data_sm[yr]['MY']!=' '), share_data_sm[yr]['MC'].astype(str) + share_data_sm[yr]['N'].astype(str) + share_data_sm[yr]['MFR'].astype(str), share_data_sm[yr]['MFR'])
File "…pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 69, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
File "…pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 96, in __radd__
    return self._arith_method(other, roperator.radd)
File "…pandas\core\frame.py", line 6864, in _arith_method
    self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=True, level=None)
File "…pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 306, in align_method_FRAME
    left, right = left.align(
File "…pandas\core\frame.py", line 4677, in align
    return super().align(
File "…pandas\core\generic.py", line 8591, in align
    return self._align_series(
File "…pandas\core\generic.py", line 8708, in _align_series
    join_index, lidx, ridx = join_index.join(
File "…pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 207, in join
    join_index, lidx, ridx = meth(self, other, how=how, level=level, sort=sort)
File "…pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3987, in join
    return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=True)
File "…pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 207, in join
    join_index, lidx, ridx = meth(self, other, how=how, level=level, sort=sort)
File "…pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3995, in join
    return self._join_monotonic(other, how=how)
File "…pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4327, in _join_monotonic
    join_array, lidx, ridx = self._outer_indexer(other)
File "…pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 345, in _outer_indexer
    joined_ndarray, lidx, ridx = libjoin.outer_join_indexer(sv, ov)
File "…pandas\_libs\join.pyx", line 562, in pandas._libs.join.outer_join_indexer
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I'll appreciate any help - how can I overcome the problem?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It is much easier to understand a problem like this given a small, hard-coded example of what `share_data_sm` contains beforehand, which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see it.

The code can be reformatted as:

```py
condition = \
    (share_data_sm[yr]['MC']!='MA') & \
    (share_data_sm[yr]['MC']!=' ') & \
    (share_data_sm[yr]['MY']!=' ')

val_if_true = share_data_sm[yr]['MC'].astype(str) + share_data_sm[yr]['N'].astype(str) + share_data_sm[yr]['MFR'].astype(str)
val_if_false = share_data_sm[yr]['MFR']
    
share_data_sm[yr]['MMR'] = np.where(condition, val_if_true, val_if_false)
```

Now you can see that the value types of `val_if_true` and `val_if_false` are different - in the first case, you add together 3 `str` values. In the second, you're keeping the datatype of `share_data_sm[yr]['MFR']`.

I bet it complains when you try to add both types into the same array.

Comment: Thank you Morton, I have followed your suggestion to review the data again. It was there - please see my answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback says the error is in the complicated

```
np.where((share_data_sm[yr]['MC']!='MA') & (share_data_sm[yr]['MC']!=' ') & (share_data_sm[yr]['MY']!=' '), share_data_sm[yr]['MC'].astype(str) + share_data_sm[yr]['N'].astype(str) + share_data_sm[yr]['MFR'].astype(str), share_data_sm[yr]['MFR'])
```

But keep in mind that it has to evaluate each of the 3 arguments before passing them to `where`.

```
(share_data_sm[yr]['MC']!='MA') & (share_data_sm[yr]['MC']!=' ') & (share_data_sm[yr]['MY']!=' ')

share_data_sm[yr]['MC'].astype(str) + share_data_sm[yr]['N'].astype(str) + share_data_sm[yr]['MFR'].astype(str)

share_data_sm[yr]['MFR']
```

It's a little hard to read the traceback, but the `str+` error suggests it in the middle argument.  But you are adding string values.

But I am seeing `this.join` and `indices` which suggests that it's trying to line up the indices of the series.  So frame indices may be mostly strings, with an oddball numeric index. But this is just a guess; I'm not a `pandas` expert.

I'd suggest evaluating those 3 arguments before hand, before using them in the `where` to better isolate the problem.  Expressions that extend over many lines are hard to debug.

Comment: Thank you hpaulj, I have followed your suggestion to review the data again. It was there - please see my answer to my question.